# Alias column name in where clause mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

Here is the MySQL code

```
select id, name, code, batch_id from subjects where batch_id=18;
```

In this query i want name to be subject name during the execution. So this is the whole problem.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. The query you are showing looks fine, what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify by example.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a column alias in the resultset?

```
select id, name as subject_name, code, batch_id 
from subjects 
where batch_id = 18
```

This changes the name of column `name` to `subject_name` in the result of the query.

I don't see what your question has to do with the `where` clause.

Comment: OK Its up to the mark